# Pass a file as an input from one python to another

Tags: python, file, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing

I have tow python files. From `file1.py` I want to call `file2.py` but with parameterized. 
Shell equivalent is: `CALL file2.bat Input.txt`

I tried using : `os.system("file2.py Input.txt")` but this is opening the text file in notepad. I want this file taken as an input in `file2.py`.

In `file2.py`, I'm checking the passed parameter as: `print(f"First Argument : {sys.argv[0]}")`

What could the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: you need to run python files by calling `python <filename>.py` you can use subprocess in python `subprocess.run(['python', 'file2.py'])` but why not just import that other module and use all the behavior from it?

Comment: @TenaciousB in the command ```subprocess.run(['python', 'file2.py'])``` where can I give ```file1.txt``` as an Input?

Comment: @fixatd tried using ```os.system``` but this is opening notepad. (not what I expect). Tried using ```subprocess.run("file2.py, Input.txt")``` but this is giving me error. Any corrections in the command?

Comment: Would you be better off creating a function or class in file2.py that interacts with your .txt file and then importing that function or class into file1.py?

Comment: it would be `subprocess.run(['python', 'file2.py', 'input.txt'])` this would be the same as the command `$ python file2.py input.txt`. Each item in the subprocess list is a "space" separator in the console if that makes sense. When executing a python file from command line you need to use python as the first word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the using `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['python', 'file2.py', 'input.txt']) # this will be relative to the current directory
```

This is kind of a "dirty" way of doing it IMO. I would personally import file2 and run the logic from the file1 module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not about os.system, but your operating system doesn't know to open .py files with python.

*sys.executable* contains full path of the currently running Python interpreter.

So the solution is:

```
 os.system(  sys.executable +  " file2.py Input.txt" )
```

It works with python, python3, if you are in your home directory and you type

```
 /usr/local/bin/python file1.py
```

Hardcoding the string "python", as in

```
subprocess.run(['python', ...
```

is not a good advice.

Comment: Using subprocess as this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/12116796) listed benefits of subprocess over os.system.

Comment: Yes, but os.system is not the root cause of your problem. An answer has to be strictly pertinent to the question; "good as a general advice" is off topic.